# How much energy did Hurricane Camille release?

Tags: tropical-cyclone

According to this article,

[Energy Hurricane Volcano](https://science.howstuffworks.com/environmental/energy/energy-hurricane-volcano-earthquake1.htm)

> we find that for a typical mature hurricane, we get numbers in the range of 1.5 x 10^12 Watts or 1.3 x 10^17 Joules/day (this is according to the Atlantic Oceanographic and Meteorological Laboratory.) But that's not all, we're just getting started. A hurricane also releases energy through the formation of clouds and rain (it takes energy to evaporate all that water). If we crunch the numbers for an average hurricane (1.5 cm/day of rain, circle radius of 665 km), we get a gigantic amount of energy: 6.0 x 10^14 Watts or 5.2 x 10^19 Joules/day!

and according to this article,

[The largest and deadliest hurricane to touch United States](https://geology.com/hurricanes/largest-hurricane/)

> Hurricane Camille of 1969 had the highest wind speed at landfall, at an estimated 190 miles per hour when it struck the Mississippi coast.

How much energy did Hurricane Camille release, which was one of the largest ones and not an average hurricane?